# Running Boggle Solver takes over an hour to run. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, performance, solver, boggle

So I am running a Boggle Solver in java on the NetBeans IDE.  When I run it, i have to quit after 10 minutes or so because it will end up taking about 2 hour to run completely.  Is there something wrong with my code or a way that will make is substantially faster?

```
public void findWords(String word, int iLoc, int jLoc, ArrayList<JLabel> labelsUsed){

    if(iLoc < 0 || iLoc >= 4 || jLoc < 0 || jLoc >= 4){
        return;
    }

    if(labelsUsed.contains(jLabels[iLoc][jLoc])){
        return;
    }

    word += jLabels[iLoc][jLoc].getText();
    labelsUsed.add(jLabels[iLoc][jLoc]);

    if(word.length() >= 3 && wordsPossible.contains(word)){
        wordsMade.add(word);
    }

    findWords(word, iLoc-1, jLoc, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc+1, jLoc, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc, jLoc-1, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc, jLoc+1, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc-1, jLoc+1, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc-1, jLoc-1, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc+1, jLoc-1, labelsUsed);
    findWords(word, iLoc+1, jLoc+1, labelsUsed);

    labelsUsed.remove(jLabels[iLoc][jLoc]);
}
```

here is where I call this method from:

```
public void findWords(){
    ArrayList <JLabel> labelsUsed = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    for(int i=0; i<jLabels.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<jLabels[i].length; j++){
            findWords(jLabels[i][j].getText(), i, j, labelsUsed);
            //System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

edit: BTW I am using a GUI and the letters on the board are displayed by using a JLabel.

Comment: What is the size of `jlabels`?

Comment: Did you try to profile your code?

Comment: What is it spending most of its time doing e.g. what does your cpu profiler say?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you run `ArrayList.contains()` (`labelsUsed.contains(..)`)a LOT of times, each is `O(n)` - you should consider using more efficient data structure - such as a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) if possible (no dupe elements).

Comment: Using a HashSet would probably help a lot.  O(1) is much better than O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing iterative and recursive approaches, so the `findWords` method is called *something like* `n^n` times instead of `n` times.

Either remove the eight `findWords...` lines of the `findWords` method, or remove the two `for` loops of your `main`.